# WP7: Dynamically adding UIElements to a LongListSelector item

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, datatemplate, longlistselector

I'm trying to add `UIElement`s to a `LongListSelector` item programmatically. I've created templates for the header, footer, items etc.

Right now I'm doing something like this (the list item template):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listItemTemplate">
     <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ItemContent}"></ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

Inside the model, I assisgn the ItemContent to a Grid, on which I'm adding different UI elements. I don't really know if this is the way to do it or if this is even possible on the LongListSelector but when scrolling the list I get a "The parameter is incorrect." exception (at first, everything seems ok and all the elements added look fine). I tried different approaches but none worked and I feel that I'm just randomly trying solutions without a certain idea. Has anyone managed to do this by using a LongListSelector (any suggestions would be greatly appreciated)?

The call stack:

`LongListSelectorPOC.dll!LongListSelectorPOC.App.Application_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 102 + 0x5 bytes C#
    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e) + 0x30 bytes

    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.Error.GetXresultForUserException(System.Exception ex) + 0x4d bytes

    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.ManagedPeerTreeUpdate(System.IntPtr oldParentElement, System.IntPtr parentElement, System.IntPtr childElement, byte bIsParentAlive, byte bKeepReferenceToParent, byte bCanCreateParent) + 0x6b bytes

    [External Code] 
    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(System.IntPtr element, float inWidth, float inHeight, out float outWidth, out float outHeight)

    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(System.Windows.FrameworkElement element, System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x26 bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x7 bytes

    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(System.IntPtr nativeTarget, double inWidth, double inHeight, out double outWidth, out double outHeight) + 0x43 bytes 
    [External Code] 
    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.Measure_WithDesiredSizeNative(System.IntPtr element, float inWidth, float inHeight, out float outWidth, out float outHeight)

    System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure_WithDesiredSize(System.Windows.UIElement element, System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x26 bytes

    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure_WithDesiredSize(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x39 bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(System.Windows.UIElement child, System.Windows.Size layoutSlotSize) + 0x42 bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.GeneratePreviousChild(int childIndex, System.Windows.Size layoutSlotSize) + 0x6f bytes

    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.GeneratePreviousItems(ref double logicalVisibleSpace, ref System.Windows.Size stackDesiredSize, System.Windows.Size layoutSlotSize, bool isHorizontal, bool adjustPositions) + 0x138 bytes

    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x4e1 bytes 
    System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(System.IntPtr nativeTarget, double inWidth, double inHeight, out double outWidth, out double outHeight) + 0x43 bytes 
    [External Code]`

Comment: What is inside ItemContent? what is it's type? @Spiri

Comment: I tried it with a Grid, a StackPanel and even with a Border with a Grid child - still got the exception when I added many items inside the LongListSelector

Comment: No @Spiri. You are binding ContentPresenter's Content to ItemContent. What is kept in this Property (ItemContent)?

Comment: Can you share how you use that datatemplate listItemTemplate?

Comment: I assign it like this: 'listSelector.ItemTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["listItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate;' and inside the model right now it's a Grid: 'public Grid ItemContent
        {
            get
            {
                return content;
            }
            set
            {
                content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ItemContent");
            }
        }'

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DataTemplateSelector` approach.

Define, for example, enum ItemType with fields `Grid`, `Border`, `StackPanel` and then in `DataTemplateSelector` class choose template using that enum.

For `DataTemplateSelector`, please look at following article: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector

Comment: As I understand this allows me to select different templates for the list items, but this is not the problem - I could work with only one template with a Grid and that would be fine. The problem is that when adding many items to the list, it crashes with "The parameter is incorrect." exception and I don't know why.

Comment: Problem is that you are trying to Bind to ContentProperty Grid Object and ContentPresenter doesnt know how to display that content (Grid)

Comment: I suspect that this is the problem and I don't know how to solve it - I'm trying other approaches that involve the runtime visual tree but I haven't reached acceptable results yet.

Comment: @Spiri believe me, you need to change the way. DataTemplateSelector and simple enum would give you all you need.

Comment: I tried the DataTemplateSelector approach (don't know if I implemented it as you tought), but the exception is still there. I added the project here if you wanna take a look: http://ge.tt/7McuI6M/v/0?c

Comment: @Spiri I see, is there any visual representation of your final goal?

Comment: Well I'm implementing this feature for a cross-platform sdk and I'd like to let the developer add whatever he wants inside a list item. I tested it with other containers, buttons, text boxes etc. The problem persists if the list is large.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObservableCollection` for `ItemContent`.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? ItemContent should be the ContentPresenter Content (or the Border Child) - how can I integrate a ObservableCollection here?